# wordpress query - next two events by metadata date

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have posts in the "events" category that have a meta-data called "start_date".

Is there a way that I can query the next two events in the system (after today's date)?

I know that I can easily get the last two events in the system, but my wordpress nor my sql is strong enough to figure out how to query the next two events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give you an idea, try the following, not tested.

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'meta_key'=>'start_date',
  'meta_value'=> now(),
  'meta_compare' => '>',
  'order' => 'DESC',
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
   echo 'List of Posts';
   $i=0;
   while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
       the_title();
       $i<2 ? $i++ : break;
   endwhile;
 }
 wp_reset_query();
```

?>

Comment: I used time() instead of now(). I also used ASC instead of DESC. But otherwise this worked. Thanks

Comment: Also, I had to be sure that my start_date value was a unix timestamp.