# Query next days from today in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a creepy site running Wordpress 2.8.5. Its purposed to show events in my state (Bahia/Brazil).
Every event has it published date as the day of the event and the theme shows future posts bypassing WP's default to display until today.
It has a slide with some featured events and this is how it now selects what is to be shown in the slides:

```
$mes = date('n');
$ano = date('Y');
query_posts("
  meta_key=dest_principal&
  meta_value=1&
  showposts=6&
  year=$ano&
  monthnum=$mes&
  order=ASC
");
```

With this code the slide shows the first 6 posts in the current month. The problem I have is not being able to show the next 6 posts begining *today*. (to be clear, by *today* i mean the day of access)
I found this entry " [wordpress query - next two events by metadata date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682804/wordpress-query-next-two-events-by-metadata-date) " but could not translate it to my need.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. Are you trying to show 6 posts starting from today and going back to the 6 previous posts? So essentially the 6 newest posts?

If so try this in place of query_posts...

```
$recent = new WP_Query("cat=3&showposts=6");
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
```

You can use the 'cat=3' to display posts from a particular category, just change the '3' to your category id. Otherwise if you don't need to do this remove this 'cat=3&'.

BTW, I have a site focused on Bahia if you're interested in a link exchange get in touch.

Comment: To show the last events is the default behavior and is what is happening now.  
What i am trying to do is to show the *next* events happening today and beyond.